# How do I include a jpgraph in tcpdf

Tags: php, google-visualization, tcpdf, jpgraph

I want to generate a PDF file with some information on it, then send it to some email address.
The information inside the PDF will contain among other stuff, a PIE that I generate using jpgraph.
Of course, the chart will be dynamic, so it's not an option to generate a static PIE and use it as a static image. For each PDF I generate, the pie will be different.
But I have no idea on how to do it **(how to include it in tcpdf)**.
This is my chart:

```
<?php // content="text/plain; charset=utf-8"
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/jpgraph_pie.php');

$sta = $_REQUEST['start'];
$sto = $_REQUEST['end'];

// Some data
$data = array($sta,$sto);
$color   = array('#2ecc71','#e74c3c');

// A new pie graph
$graph = new PieGraph(400,400,'auto');

// Don't display the border
$graph->SetFrame(false);

// Uncomment this line to add a drop shadow to the border
// $graph->SetShadow();

// Setup title
$graph->title->Set("Procentaj realizat");
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD,18);
$graph->title->SetMargin(8); // Add a little bit more margin from the top

// Create the pie plot
$p1 = new PiePlotC($data);

// Set size of pie
$p1->SetSize(0.35);

// Label font and color setup
$p1->value->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD,12);
$p1->value->SetColor('white');

$p1->value->Show();

// Setup the title on the center circle
$p1->midtitle->Set("Procent\nraspunsuri corecte\n83%");
$p1->midtitle->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_NORMAL,14);

// Set color for mid circle
$p1->SetMidColor('white');

// Use percentage values in the legends values (This is also the default)
$p1->SetLabelType(PIE_VALUE_PER);

$p1->SetSliceColors($color);

// The label array values may have printf() formatting in them. The argument to the
// form,at string will be the value of the slice (either the percetage or absolute
// depending on what was specified in the SetLabelType() above.
$lbl = array("corecte\n%.1f%%","gresite\n%.1f%%");
$p1->SetLabels($lbl);

// Uncomment this line to remove the borders around the slices
// $p1->ShowBorder(false);

// Add drop shadow to slices
$p1->SetShadow();

// Explode all slices 15 pixels
$p1->ExplodeAll(15);

// Add plot to pie graph
$graph->Add($p1);

// .. and send the image on it's marry way to the browser
$graph->Stroke();

?>
```

So the above code is in a file called mychart.php. I want to include into a tcpdf file the result of this. How can I do this?

It's not mandatory that I use jpgraph. I see that google charts look quite perfect and seem easy to use. 
I could use this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Corecte', 83]          
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 250,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when including into a tcpdf... they still have a problem... I mean, I heave to add a script inside the HTML of the tcpdf, and the problem is that it seems tcpdf only takes the body tag ... 
So what can I do?
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same requirement for graphs embedded in TCPDF. [Click here to see my  code](http://pastebin.com/uQAAHEUy).

**Explanation:**

What you would need to do is capture the output of JPGraph using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` and then use `TCPDF::Image()` to display the graph, prefixed by the @ symbol (which tells TCPDF that it is dealing with an image data stream and not an image file name). You can [see more about this in the TCPDF examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_009.phps).

You will probably need to play around with the graph dimensions as well as the `TCPDF::setImageScale()` and `TCPDF::setJPEGQuality()` methods to get the graph to render sharper. I found that values of 1.7 for the scale and 80 for the quality provided a good balance.